# Square of factorial as the value of iterated derivative at zero

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let $k$ be a positive integer and let a function $y$ satisfy the following differential equation:
$$x^4y'' + (2k+5)x^3y'+\left (x^2(k+2)^2+x-1\right )y+1=0.$$I want to see whether the relation $y^{(k-1)}(0)=[(k-1)!]^2$ holds. This is evidently true for $k=1$ by setting $x=0$ in the equation. I think the use of mathematical induction on $k$ is to no avail because of the coefficients $x^3$ and $x^4$ appeared in the equation for $y'$ and $y''$, respectively. Can anyone help?
Thanks!